# About consistency and maximality in Łukasiewicz logic

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

Suppose that we define consistency in Łukasiewicz logic as follows:

> - We say  formula $\varphi$ is consistent if $\nvdash \neg \varphi$.
> - We say a finite set $\Gamma= \{\psi_1, \dotsc, \psi_n\}$ is consistent if $(\psi_1\&\dotsb\&\psi_n)$ is consistent.
> - We say an infinite set $\Gamma$ is consistent if all finite subsets of $\Gamma$ are consistent.

And also define maximality as follows:

> - We say a set $\Phi$ is maximal if for all $\varphi\notin \Phi$, $\Phi\cup \{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent.

Then we are able to prove the following:

If $\Phi$ is a maximal and consistent set, then for all formulæ $\varphi$ and $\psi$:

1. $\varphi\&\psi\in \Phi$ if and only if $\varphi\in\Phi$ and $\psi\in\Phi$,
2. If $\varphi\in \Phi$ and $\varphi\rightarrow \psi\in \Phi$, then $\psi\in \Phi$,
3. If $\vdash \varphi$, then $\varphi\in \Phi$,
4. $\varphi\in \Phi$ or $\neg \varphi\in \Phi$.

Proof Sketches:

**1**:

> Let $\varphi\&\psi\in \Phi$ and $\varphi\notin \Phi$. Thus by definition $\Phi\cup \{\varphi\}$ is not consistent. So there is a finite set $\Gamma\subset\Phi$ such that $\Gamma\cup \{\varphi\}$ is not consistent. Let $\Gamma=\{\psi_1,\dotsc,\psi_n\}$, hence by the inconsistency of $\Gamma\cup \{\varphi\}$ we have $\vdash \neg (\psi_1\&\dotsb\&\psi_n\&\varphi)$. Since $\Gamma\cup \{\psi,\varphi\}$ is not consistent, then we have $\vdash \neg (\psi_1\&\dotsb\&\psi_n\&\varphi\&\psi)$, and since $\Gamma\cup \{\varphi\&\psi\}\subset \Phi$, then we obtain a contradiction to the Aconsistency of $\Phi$.

> For other direction assume $\varphi\in \Phi$, $\psi \in \Phi$ and $\varphi \,\&\, \psi \notin \Phi$. Then $\Phi \cup \{\varphi\,\&\, \psi\} $ is not consistent, and there is a finite set  $\Gamma = \{\psi_1, \dotsc, \psi_n\}$, where $\Gamma\subset \Phi$ such that $\vdash\neg (\psi_1\,\&\, \dotsb\,\& \,\psi_n\,\&\, \varphi \,\&\,\psi)$. But this states that the finite subset $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi,\psi\} \subset \Phi$ is not consistent.

**2**:

> Let $\varphi \in \Phi$ and $\varphi \rightarrow \psi \in \Phi$. If $\psi \notin \Phi$, then $\Phi \cup \{\psi\}$ is inconsistent and there exists a finite subset $\Gamma \subset \Phi$ such that $\Gamma \cup \{\psi\}$ is inconsistent. Let $\Gamma = \{\psi_1, \dotsc, \psi_n\}$, so we have:
>
> \begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq_inconsistent} \vdash \neg (\psi_1\,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_n \,\&\, \psi). \end{equation}
>
> On the other hand, it can be proven that from $\vdash \chi\rightarrow \chi$ and  $(\varphi\& (\varphi \rightarrow  \psi)) \rightarrow \psi$ we have  $\vdash(\chi \rightarrow \chi)\,\&\, ((\varphi \,\&\,(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow \psi)$ and by considering an instance of $((\varphi_1 \rightarrow \psi_1) \& (\varphi_2 \rightarrow \psi_2)) \rightarrow ((\varphi_1 \&\varphi_2) → (\psi_1 \&\psi_2)))$ and applying (MP) we obtain $$\vdash\chi \,\&\, (\varphi \,\&\, (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow (\chi \,\&\, \psi).$$ Then by replacing $\psi_1\,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\,\psi_n$ instead of $\chi$ we have: $$\vdash (\psi_1\,\&\,\dotsb\,\&\, \psi_n \,\&\, \varphi \,\&\,(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow (\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_n \,\& \,\psi ).$$ Now, by using $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (\neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \varphi)$ scheme, which is provable in Łukasiewicz logic we have:
>
> \begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq013}  \vdash\neg (\psi_1 \,\&\, \cdots \,\&\, \psi_n \& \psi ) \rightarrow \neg (\psi_1\,\&\,\cdots\,\&\, \psi_n \,\&\, \varphi \,\&\,(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)). \end{equation}
>
> By applying (MP) on \eqref{eq_inconsistent}, \eqref{eq013} we obtain $\vdash \neg (\psi_1\,\&\,\dotsb\,\&\, \psi_n \,\&\, \varphi \,\&\,(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)) $. But this means that  $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi, \varphi\rightarrow \psi\}\subset \Phi$ is inconsistent, which is a contradiction to the consistency of $\Phi$.

**3**:

> Let $\vdash \varphi$. By soundness in Łukasiewicz logic we have $\neg \varphi \equiv \bot$, which means that $\neg \varphi$ is semantically equivalent to $\bot$. If $\varphi \notin \Phi$, then by maximality definition $\Phi\cup \{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent. So there is a subset $\Gamma = \{\psi_1,\dotsc, \psi_n\} \subset \Phi$, such that $\Gamma\cup \{\varphi\}$ is not consistent. Therefore $$\begin{array}{llll} (1) & & \vdash\neg (\psi_1\,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_n \,\&\, \varphi) & \text{inconsistency of } \Gamma \cup \{\varphi\}\\ (2) & & \vdash\neg \psi_1 \veebar\dotsb \veebar \neg\psi_n \veebar \neg \varphi & (1),\text{Ł}5 \\ (3) & & \vdash\neg (\neg \psi_1 \veebar\dotsb \veebar \neg\psi_n) \rightarrow \neg \varphi & (2), \text{Ł}7 \\ (4) & & \vdash\neg (\neg \psi_1 \veebar\dotsb \veebar \neg\psi_n) \rightarrow \perp & (3), \text{assumption and replacement} \\ (5) & & \vdash(\neg \neg \psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \neg \neg \psi_n) \rightarrow \perp & (4), \text{Ł}6 \\ (6)  & & \vdash(\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_n) \rightarrow \perp & (5), \text{Ł}11\\ (7) & & \vdash\neg (\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\,\psi_n) & (6),\text{Ł}15 \end{array}$$ Thus from $\vdash \neg (\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\,\psi_n)$, we have $\Gamma$ is inconsistent. But this is a contradiction with the consistency of $\Phi$.

**4**:

> Suppose that there is a formula $\varphi$ such that  $\varphi\notin \Phi$ and $\neg \varphi \notin \Phi$. From the maximality and consistency of $\Phi$, neither  $\Phi \cup \{\varphi\}$ nor $\Phi \cup \{\neg \varphi\}$ is consistent. Assume  $\Gamma = \{\psi_1, \dotsc, \psi_m\}$ is a finite subset of $\Phi$ for which  $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent, then the following deduction is valid:
> $$\begin{array}{llll}
> (1)& &\vdash \neg (\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsc \,\&\, \psi_m \,\&\,\varphi) & \text{inconsistency of } \Gamma\cup \{\varphi\}\\
> (2)& & \vdash \neg \psi_1 \veebar \dotsb \veebar \neg \psi_m \veebar \neg \varphi & (1), \text{Ł} 5\\ 
> (3)& &\vdash \neg (\neg \psi_1 \veebar \dotsb \veebar \neg \psi_m ) \rightarrow \neg \varphi & (2), \text{Ł}7 \\
> (4)& &\vdash (\neg\neg \psi_1 \,\&\, \cdots \,\&\,\neg\neg\psi_m ) \rightarrow \neg \varphi  & (3), \text{Ł}6 \\
> (5)& & \vdash (\psi_1 \,\&\, \cdots \,\&\,\psi_m ) \rightarrow \neg \varphi & (4), \text{Ł}11.
> \end{array}$$
> Thus from **3** we have $(\psi_1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_m )\rightarrow \neg \varphi \in \Phi$, since $\Gamma=\{\psi_1, \dotsc, \psi_m\}\subset \Phi$ then we have $(\psi _1 \,\&\, \dotsb \,\&\, \psi_m) \in \Phi$, by **1**. So from **2** we have $\neg \varphi \in \Phi$, which is a  contradiction with the assumption  $\neg \varphi \notin \Phi$.

My question is about the strange set $\{\neg(x\& x), \neg(\neg x\&\neg x)\}$. It is easy to see that this set is consistent, and so it can be extended to a maximal and consistent set $\Theta$.
By maximality of $\Theta$ and the above statements (Number **4**), we have $(x\& x)\notin  \Theta$ and $(\neg x \& \neg x) \notin \Theta$. So by number **1**, $x\notin \Theta$ and also $\neg x\notin \Theta$. But this can not be possible.
Why does this happen? What is the problem with this consistency definition and the maximality? Or am I missing something important?

---

Edit:
By $\&$ we mean strong conjuction. That its semantics informally is $V(x \& y) = \max\{0, x + y -1\}$.

Also, the Łukasiewicz theorems used in the proofs are as follows:
$$\begin{array}{llcll}
(\text{Ł}5) & \neg (\varphi \,\&\, \psi) \leftrightarrow (\neg \varphi \veebar \neg \psi) & \quad &
(\text{Ł}6)& \neg (\varphi \veebar \psi) \leftrightarrow (\neg \varphi \, \& \, \neg \psi) \\
(\text{Ł}7)& (\varphi \veebar \psi) \leftrightarrow (\neg \varphi \rightarrow \psi) & \quad&(\text{Ł}11) & \neg \neg \varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi\\
(\text{Ł}15) &(\varphi \rightarrow \perp) \leftrightarrow \neg \varphi & & & 
\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate or helpful to hide parts of a question inside spoiler boxes. If you are asking us to help you, then provide all the information that you think is relevant and then let us decide what we want to read. Spoiler boxes on MSE are for use in answers to let the OP see if they can fill in details for themselves.

Comment: @RobArthan I felt lots of notation may make distraction from the main question. So I decided to make spoiler part in order to provide the proofs for who want to check it.

Comment: Thanks for removing the spoiler boxes. I think there is also a typo in the last paragraph: I think you meant to say "we have ... $\lnot x \& \lnot x \not\in \Theta$". Sorry about all this textual criticism - I will try to find some time to look into the mathematics.

Comment: Sorry, but you also need to clarify whether $\&$ is the weak or strong conjunction in your notation.

Comment: MathJax note: MathJax obeys `\eqref`, so you might as well use it if you are going to the trouble of `\label`ling anyway. But it does *not* obey `\L`, so you must manually type Ł. I have edited accordingly. In **4**, you switched from justifying by, say, $L5$ to justifying by $\textŁ5$; but I wasn't sure whether this was an intentional distinction, so I didn't edit. TeX note: something like `\def\land{\mathbin\&}` (or you can avoid the existing name) can save you from having repeatedly to type `\,\&\,`, and from having to decide manually when to use just `\&`.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks for mentioning the typo in the last paragraph. Also (At)LSpice Thanks for the edits and information about \eqref.